# Logstash restart slow with large persistent queue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a logstash server that somehow stopped listening on its syslog input (but didn't crash thats odd enough on itself but case for another question), it was configured to have a max queue of 100GB and, after some time (31gb of queue) i decided to restart it.

After restarting logstash it gets "stuck" on

```
[INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

and it doesnt start sending to Elasticsearch the messages on the queue (neither the ones on the queue nor newly received ones).

If i delete the queue folder and restart logstash then I get new events but obviously I lost all the old ones.

Why is logstash taking so long to process the persistent queue when its big? are there any settings i should tune to make the pipeline flow ?

I have saved the old Persistent Queue for looking deeper into it, any pointers?

Comment: How many pipeline.workers, pipeline.batch.size you have configured for you logstash pipelines?

Details here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.16/tuning-logstash.html

Comment: @Ankit i'm currently using (pipeline.batch.size: 4000) and (pipeline.workers: 8)